# Holding Sockets open in Java

Tags: java, sockets

Just wondering, I have been tasked with creating a program to implement the Two-Phase Commit Protocol across several servers with unique databases. I have so far got everything working that I need to - it works for a theoretical n number of servers. However, I want the program to stay open after the protocol is over, yet it closes every time, most times with a large error as follows:

`java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:163)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at dcs.os.Server.queryDatabase(Server.java:162)
    at dcs.os.Server.lambda$processClient$1(Server.java:266)
    at dcs.os.Server$$Lambda$2/200825655.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

I think I'd need to put a 'while(true)' loop in, but I've tried and it doesn't work. Any ideas how to edit my code so the servers can be queried multiple times without re-running the program? The code is as follows:

```
int serverListenPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); // The port that this server should listen on to accept connections from other servers
int clientListenPort = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); // The port that this server should listen on to accept connections from clients
InetSocketAddress[] otherServerAddresses = Server.parseAddresses(args[3]); // The addresses of the other servers

String databasePath = args[4]; // The path to the database file
MyServer server = new MyServer(databasePath);

if (args[1].endsWith("LastServer")) {
    server.setTail();
    args[1] = args[1].substring(0, args[1].indexOf('L'));
}

server.setServers(otherServerAddresses);

try{

    server.acceptClients(clientListenPort);
    int serverNo = (serverListenPort-8999) / 2;

    System.out.println(serverNo);

    if (serverNo == 1) {
        server.setHead();
    }

    server.acceptServers(serverListenPort);
    System.out.println("Closing server");
    server.close();
} catch {...} finally {...}
```

Additional code that has been requested:

```
public void acceptServers(int port) throws IOException {

    if (acceptSS != null && acceptSS.isBound()) {
        acceptSS.close();
    }

    acceptSS = new ServerSocket(port);
    returnSock = acceptSS.accept();

    OutputStream os = returnSock.getOutputStream();
    InputStream is = returnSock.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    StockList request = request = new StockList();
    int itemCount = is.read();

    for (int i=0; i<itemCount; i++) {

        String item = in.readLine();
        int amount = Integer.decode(in.readLine()).intValue();
        request.add(item, amount);

    }

    StockList dbStock = queryDatabase();
    byte success = 0;
    if (dbStock.enough(request)) {
        success = 1;
    }

    os.write(success);

    if (is.read()==1) {
        System.out.println("COMMIT");
        dbStock.remove(request);
        writeDatabase(dbStock);
    }

    returnSock.close();
    acceptSS.close();

}

@Override
public void connectServers(InetSocketAddress[] servers) throws IOException {

    commSocks = new Socket[servers.length];
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    for (int i=0; i<commSocks.length; i++) {
        commSocks[i] = new Socket();
        System.out.println(servers[i]);
        commSocks[i].connect(servers[i]);
        System.out.println("Connected.");
    }

}
```

Comment: where is the actual socket code? accept() and such

Comment: @gidim Updated for the extra code

Comment: A socket is kept open until you close it or times out.

Comment: What part of 'closed by interrupt' don't you understand? You can't defend against that, but you can remove whatever code is doing the interrupt.

Comment: @m0skit0 Until you close it or it is closed by an interrupt. Timeouts do not close sockets.

Comment: What does `isBound()` have to do with whether you should close a `ServerSocket`? and why are you creating a new `ServerSocket` per `accept()`? and how do you expect multiple clients to be able to connect to that? and why aren't you creating a new thread per accepted socket? You need to read a networking tutorial. This is all wrong from start to finish. See the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the correction. But what does an exception like `java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)` mean?